# Scene explanation from Citizen X

Tags: plot-explanation, character, analysis, citizen-x

In the movie Citizen X, there is a scene where Donald Sutherland’s character (Festisov) heaps praise on Stephen Rea’s character (Bukarov).  Bukarov abruptly stands up, and Festisov says,

> Bukarov, I am sorry.  You may go.

My gut reaction is that Bukarov is embarrassed by the praise, and is leaving the room to be alone, but Festisov reacts in a way that leads me to believe he has accidentally committed a grave sin.

I know it’s an old movie, but does anyone remember, and have an alternative take on that scene / know of either of the actor’s talking about the movie?